# My step amcharts disappears with too many data points

Tags: amcharts

I'm using amcharts v3 AmGraph to display some changing thresholds across time. Currently using the step type with noStepRisers set to true.

```
var thresholdGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
thresholdGraph.balloonText = "[[category]] <b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Activity Thresholds: [[Threshold]] L/h</span></b>";
thresholdGraph.gapPeriod = 0;
thresholdGraph.id = "Threshold";
thresholdGraph.lineColor = "#CC0000";
thresholdGraph.markerType = "line";
thresholdGraph.minDistance = 0;
thresholdGraph.noStepRisers = true;
thresholdGraph.stepDirection = "right";
thresholdGraph.title = "Activity Thresholds";
thresholdGraph.type = "step";
thresholdGraph.valueField = "Threshold";
FC_consumption_by_TimeSeries.addGraph(thresholdGraph);
```

Our data points is every 5 minutes. When we select 1.5 days of data (432 data points), the threshold "disappears" on a 13" monitor [[demo 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Tcg.png) (the tooltip still displays), but it displays on a 22.9" monitor [[demo 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZNMG.png). When we select 7 days of data (2016 data points), the threshold does not show on the 22.9" monitor either [[demo 3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XkMt.png). But when we zoom using the amcharts function, the threshold reappears [[demo 4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXKnf.png), but the chart becomes "dashed" because of the noStepRisers?

Also, if noStepRisers is set to false, the threshold always appears with the vertical lines.
[[demo 5]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leswt.png)

I suspect there is a minimum pixel width to the stepRisers which is preventing the steps from showing.
The **end goal** is to have threshold lines always with no "stepRisers".

My 1st post in stackoverflow, please let me know if more details are required. Any ideas/known issues/workarounds/previous discussion links welcome. Please help!